# Why does getch return three values when I press a function or arrow key?

Tags: c++, input

I am attempting to write a program that will quit upon the user pressing the F1 key. I am using a custom function, myGetch() to get user input from the terminal. It simply gets user input directly from the terminal, without the user having to press enter.

I made a little program to print out the keycodes, with the goal of finding what keycode F1 outputs so I can use that keycode instead of "127" for the "Delete" key to quit the program.

```
#include <termios.h>
char myGetch() { 
    char buf = 0;
    struct termios old = {0};
    if (tcgetattr(0, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr()");
    old.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    old.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    old.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    old.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old) < 0)
        perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
    if (read(0, &buf, 1) < 0)
        perror ("read()");
    old.c_lflag |= ICANON;
    old.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old) < 0)
        perror ("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
    return (buf);
}


int main() {
    int c = 0;
    while(c != 127) { // Delete key is 127
        c = myGetch();
        std::cout << "Input: " << c << "\n" << endl;
    }
    std::cout << "User pressed delete!" << endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

It works as you might expect. You type in a key and it's printed back to you. If you press delete, the program exits. However, what's odd is that if you press, say, the up arrow, you get output that looks like this:

```
Input: 27
Input: 91
Input: 65
```

Output for function keys and the other arrow keys look similar.

std::cout is only called once. So why is it printing three times? I would like my program to detect the user pressing F1, then quit. But I don't see how to do this if my program is behaving in this manner.

Any help is much appreciated. My platform is Mac OSX, if it is pertinent.

Comment: It's basically the same reason the sky is blue, and why water is wet. These keys generate three character codes because these keys generate three character codes. There is no law that requires each key to generate exactly one byte to read. Each physical key can generate multiple character codes. High end programmable keyboards have programmable keys you can set up yourself to generate multiple keypresses, with one key.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is there any way I can suppress this behavior and instead make is output one byte? I.e. check if char c is equal to 279165?

Comment: If my memory serves, all the platforms I've been on have had certain keys generate multiple key codes.  I usually rely on something like NCurses to make it easy to write portable code.  (Well, portable as long as NCurses exists on all the platforms I care about.)

Comment: @Eljay My only concern with Ncurses has always been that it's not windows compatible. Or is it?

Comment: A single char value can store only a single value in the range 0-255 (or -128 to 127). It is not possible to meaningfully store  value of 279165 in a single `char` value,  according to fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe. Computers don't work this way.

Comment: @shades: http://pdcurses.org I haven't tried it, since I don't have Windows, but I've heard it works.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well that clears it up. I still don't know how I'm going to parse c to check if it's an arrow key, but thank you for explaining why it works that way. Would you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading input one character, one byte at a time; however pressing a single key may not necessarily generate one character. The cursor-up key generates three characters when pressed, `ESC [ A`, which is a common mapping for a cursor-up key [in the ANSI/VT100 series of terminal emulators](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

Even letters itself will generate multiple characters when using a non-English keyboard mapping. For example, pressing the cyrillic letter "а", on a Cyrillic keyboard, reads two characters: 208, 176.

Note that the "ESC" key itself reads a single ESC character. After reading an `ESC` there's nothing to indicate whether this is a standalone "Esc" keypress, or a first of many possible multi-character sequences that represent special keys.

Terminal libraries, like *curses* typically take the approach of starting a short timeout after reading an ESC from the terminal. If no further characters arrive they presume that ESC was pressed by itself. If more characters are immediately read they will try to look up what special key the read character sequence represents.

When reading the terminal yourself, it's up to you to do all this work. Nothing else will do the work for you.